# Adding an element inside a wildcard type ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

I am trying to add an element in a list where the list type parameter is a wildcard that extends Question

```
    ArrayList<? extends Question> id  = new ArrayList<? extends Question>();
    id.add(new Identification("What is my name?","some",Difficulty.EASY));
    map.put("Personal", id);
```

Where identification is a subclass of Question. QUestion is an abstract class.

it is giving me this error

On Line #1 `Cannot instantiate the type ArrayList<? extends Question>`

And on Line #2

```
The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Question) in the type ArrayList<capture#2-of ? extends Question> is not applicable for the arguments (Identification)
```

Why is it showing an error like that? What is causing it? And how would I fix it?

Comment: `ArrayList<? extends Question>` means a *an `ArrayList` of some __unknown__ type of `Question`s*. This is neither sufficient information for creating an object (*which* kinds of `Questions`?) nor does it safely allow you to add `Identification`s. Perhaps you wanted an `ArrayList<Identification>` or `ArrayList<Question>`?

Comment: @veer The thing is. I wanted to add other subtype of Question like MultipleChoice etc etc.THe List itself will not only contain a list of identification but also Multiplication or other subtypes of QUestion.

Comment: ... then you want `ArrayList<Question>` :-) That will allow *any* `Question`s to be added to the list.

Comment: Why is that allowed? I thought the rule of inheritance doesn't apply when it comes to Type parameters?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with "*rules of inheritance ... apply ... to Type parameters*", this has to do with the fact that any `MultipleChoice` or `Identification` are `Question`s.

Comment: @veer looks like I misunderstood that concept regarding type parameters. So this means I can add any subtype of Question to the arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the following scenario:

```
List<MultipleChoiceQuestion> questions = new ArrayList<MultipleChoiceQuestion>();
List<? extends Question> wildcard = questions;
wildcard.add(new FreeResponseQuestion()); // pretend this compiles

MultipleChoiceQuestion q = questions.get(0); // uh oh...
```

Adding something to a wildcard collection is dangerous because you don't know what kind of `Question` it actually contains. It *could* be `FreeResponseQuestion`s, but it could also not be, and if it isn't then you're going to get `ClassCastException`s somewhere down the road. Since adding something to a wildcard collection will almost always fail, they decided to turn the runtime exception into a compile time exception and save everyone some trouble.

Why would you want to create an `ArrayList<? extends Question>`? It would be next to useless because you cannot add anything to it for the above reason. You almost certainly want to omit the wildcard entirely:

```
List<Question> id = new ArrayList<Question>();
id.add(new Identification(...));
```