# Covariance of generics

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between 'super' and 'extends' in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics)
>   [Java Generics WildCard Question: List<? extends A>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495383/java-generics-wildcard-question-list-extends-a)

I discovered a strange behaviour of Java generics that I can't explain to myself.

If I try the following code, I would expect that it should work

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Integer(2));
list.add(new Float(2.0f));
```

But this leads to an compiler error.

If I change the first line to

```
List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

it works fine for the compiler.

Can anyone explain that to me?
What is the difference between **? extends** and **? super** ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082780/adding-an-element-inside-a-wildcard-type-arraylist

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics and the links in that question.

Answer (score 1):

See Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 28:

Producer extends, Consumer super

If your parameter is a producer, it should be `<? extends T>`, if it's a consumer it has to be `<? super T>`

Here it is consumer so it must be `<? super Number>`